# ¿Cómo poner la ruta de una imagen si tengo el nombre almacenado?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, imagen, fileupload, src

Tengo una imagen y su nombre está almacenado en la base de datos y movido a una carpeta. El nombre de la imagen siempre cambia cuando agregan una nueva.

Estoy utilizando *ReactJS* y *NodeJS*:

```
<div className={classes.imagePreview}>
    <img alt="Remy Sharp" src={`/${user_photo}`} />
</div>
```

El nombre se muestra correctamente pero no sé que ruta poner o cómo podría pintarla.

Comment: Cuando el usuario sube una nueva foto por primera vez, esta se debe ir a una carpeta y debe de dársele como nombre un _UUID_; además, este identificador debe estar asociado al usuario **y no debería cambiar**. Cuando el usuario suba una nueva foto, debe recuperar el _UUID_ y reemplazar la foto actual en el directorio. De esta manera tu front nunca cambia y solo necesitas: `<img src={`${avatarsPath}/${user.photo}.jpeg`} />`.

Comment: Gracias por responder, a si tengo guardado el nombre de la imagen, lo que nose es como poner la ruta antes del nombre. por ejemplo cree una carpeta que se llama photo dentro de src. tambien intente ponerla en public/assets/images. pero nose como acceder a la ruta, gracias

Comment: Para aclarar: e folder de imágenes no debería estar dentro de tu aplicación, debe estar en tu servidor y exponerlo por HTTP. En tu caso, pon el folder de imágenes dentro de `public/` y en tu URL pon: `<img src={`%PUBLIC_URL%/${user_photo}`} />`. Más información: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: Esto no me funciono, no he podido resolverlo

Comment: Ya me funciono y es que me faltaba agregar algo de configuración

con este código funciono:

this.express.use('/imagenes', express.static(__dirname + '/imagenes'))